# Error installing nvidia driver Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia

I'm having trouble installing driver for GTX980 on Ubuntu 14.04. I need to upgrade to CUDA7.5 and latest driver. I used both the .run installer and deb. installer and do the purging before the installation.

Here is the log:

```
Using built-in stream user interface
-> Detected 8 CPUs online; setting concurrency level to 8.
-> License accepted by command line option.
-> Installing NVIDIA driver version 352.39.
-> There appears to already be a driver installed on your system (version: 352.39).  As part of installing this driver (version: 352.39), the existing driver will be uninstalled.
  Are you sure you want to continue? (Answer: Continue installation)
-> Running distribution scripts
   executing: '/usr/lib/nvidia/pre-install'...
-> done.
-> The distribution-provided pre-install script failed!  Are you sure you want to continue? (Answer: Continue installation)
WARNING: One or more modprobe configuration files to disable Nouveau are already present at: /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-installer-disable-nouveau.conf.  Please be sure you have reboo
ted your system since these files were written.  If you have rebooted, then Nouveau may be enabled for other reasons, such as being included in the system initial ramdisk or in y
our X configuration file.  Please consult the NVIDIA driver README and your Linux distribution's documentation for details on how to correctly disable the Nouveau kernel driver.
-> For some distributions, Nouveau can be disabled by adding a file in the modprobe configuration directory.  Would you like nvidia-installer to attempt to create this modprobe f
ile for you? (Answer: Yes)
-> One or more modprobe configuration files to disable Nouveau have been written.  For some distributions, this may be sufficient to disable Nouveau; other distributions may requ
ire modification of the initial ramdisk.  Please reboot your system and attempt NVIDIA driver installation again.  Note if you later wish to reenable Nouveau, you will need to de
lete these files: /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-installer-disable-nouveau.conf
-> Would you like to register the kernel module sources with DKMS? This will allow DKMS to automatically build a new module, if you install a different kernel later. (Answer: Yes
)
-> Installing both new and classic TLS OpenGL libraries.
-> Installing both new and classic TLS 32bit OpenGL libraries.
-> Install NVIDIA's 32-bit compatibility libraries? (Answer: Yes)
-> Uninstalling the previous installation with /usr/bin/nvidia-uninstall.
-> nvidia-installer will install the libvdpau and libvdpau_trace libraries that were included with this installer package. These libraries are available separately through the li
bvdpau project and will be removed from the NVIDIA Linux driver installer package in the future, so it is recommended that VDPAU users install libvdpau separately, e.g. by using
packages available from their distributions, or by building from the sources available at:

http://people.freedesktop.org/~aplattner/vdpau
-> Searching for conflicting files:
-> done.
-> Installing 'NVIDIA Accelerated Graphics Driver for Linux-x86_64' (352.39):
   executing: '/sbin/ldconfig'...
-> done.
-> Driver file installation is complete.
-> Installing DKMS kernel module:
ERROR: Failed to run `/usr/sbin/dkms build -m nvidia -v 352.39 -k 3.13.0-55-generic`:
Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...                                                                                                    

Building module:                                                                                                                                                
cleaning build area....                                                                                                                                         
make KERNELRELEASE=3.13.0-55-generic module KERNEL_UNAME=3.13.0-55-generic; make -C uvm module KERNEL_UNAME=3.13.0-55-generic KBUILD_EXTMOD=/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/352.39/build/uvm.
...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for nvidia: 352.39 not found                                                                                                
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.13.0-55-generic (x86_64)                                                                                 
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/352.39/build/make.log for more information.                                                                                        
-> error.                                                                                                                                                       
ERROR: Failed to install the kernel module through DKMS. No kernel module was installed; please try installing again without DKMS, or check the DKMS logs for more information.
ERROR: Installation has failed.  Please see the file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for details.  You may find suggestions on fixing installation problems in the README availabl
e on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hi I have GTX 980 Ti using Ubuntu 14.04 (I tested with GTX 970 also). I'm not sure why but installing the driver twice from different sources worked.

1. Download driver file from [NVidia's website](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us), e.g. "NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-352.55.run".
2. Firstly install from repository

run in terminal:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove nvidia*
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

3. Restart. You will find that you cannot login again. Before login, press `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F1`. Enter your username and password in the command.
4. Stop the lightdm and run NVidia's install file:

run in terminal:

```
$ sudo stop lightdm
$ sudo cd ~/Downloads
$ sudo chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-352.55.run
$ sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-352.55.run
```

Here some files will be installed and in the end the program says kernel error but it's ok. Restart again, the graphic card will work.

Comment: for those of you using Ubuntu 17.04: if sudo stop lightdm doesn't work. Try sudo service lightdm stop

Comment: This https://askubuntu.com/questions/841876/how-to-disable-nouveau-kernel-driver, Driver download and run worked for me. Thanks