# Unable to load the "nvidia-drm" kernel module

Tags: ubuntu, graph, nvidia

I am trying to install Nvidia driver on Ubuntu. I am following the structure mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32728341/error-installing-nvidia-driver-ubuntu-14-04), but still the above error coming up.

Comment: Does your system boot from UEFI and secure Boot option is turned on in the BIOS setting? if so-  turn it off and the problem will be solved.

Comment: try https://askubuntu.com/questions/742857/dual-gpu-nvidia-940m-intel-sky-lake first answer